# Flights info for Choluteca?

Tags: flight-search-engines

Choluteca (Honduras) has an airport, but that fact is unknown to Kayak, Kiwi, Adioso, and Momondo.  How can I find info on flights to/from there?

Two-hour drive from TGU.  Five hours from SAL but FLL-SAL much cheaper than FLL-TGU.  So if not too expensive (compared to car rental), a flight is preferred.  There are buses but I think they are either slow or expensive.

There have been [commercial flights since April 2017](https://www.bnamericas.com/en/news/infrastructure/honduras-opens-passenger-terminal-at-choluteca-airport#696664), but I do not know where from/to.

Comment: Expedia has the gall to serve Choluteca up for SEO but change it to TGU if I click on it.  Similar behavior from TripAdvisor.

Comment: Are you sure there are _any_ scheduled passenger flights from Choluteca? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choluteca_Airport) makes no mention of any, and it doesn't seem to have a IATA code. It's not mentioned in bold at [List of airports in Honduras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_Honduras) either.

Comment: It looks like they [built a passenger terminal last year](https://www.bnamericas.com/en/news/infrastructure/honduras-opens-passenger-terminal-at-choluteca-airport), which would be a first step toward scheduled passenger flights, but I'm not seeing any sign that there are any yet. You could presumably pay someone to fly you there, though that would end up rather costly.

Comment: If I were sure, I wouldn't have asked.  Wikipedia is a stub, so it's not helpful.  Charter cost would be ridiculous.  Rather do the five-hour drive and see things along the way.   (BTW,why a vote to close without a reason?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CM Airlines](http://www.cmairlines.com/) is supposed to fly to Choluteca. Per [this article](http://www.interairports.hn/cm-apertura-vuelos-desde-toncontin-hacia-choluteca/), they were set in April 2017 to fly from Toncontín Airport (TGU) to Chouluteca on Monday, Tuesday, and Friday, and the service did, in fact, [begin](https://www.transponder1200.com/cm-airlines-inicia-operaciones-tegucigalpa-choluteca/).

However, when I go to their website and try to search for flights, there are none listed between now and December. Choluteca still appears in the popup search boxes, but not on their destinations page.

I haven't been able to find any news articles reporting that the service was discontinued, but it doesn't seem to be available for booking. You might contact the airline, perhaps [on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/cmairlines/) or [Twitter](https://twitter.com/cmairlines), for further information on whether it's actually been cancelled.

Comment: The menu says I can get there from GUA, LCE, PEU, RTB, SAP, TGU but not from SAL, which is what I've already bought.  But SAP also gives "no flights found."  Your answer gave me an idea that I _should_ have thought of—to search in Spanish.  Unfortunately, that gives me the same thing I saw in English: pages that told Google "Choluteca" for SEO, but then show TGU when you click on them.  Unless another viable option turns up, I guess I'll drive but look around both airports to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: Turns out driving ain't gonna happen.
https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/121339/